# Nginx Doesn't serve Static Files

Tags: nginx, django, fastcgi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [nginx+django serving static files](https://serverfault.com/questions/370525/nginxdjango-serving-static-files)

I followed this [guide](http://www.rkblog.rk.edu.pl/w/p/django-nginx/) to deploy Django + Nginx on Ubuntu 11.10. Django works well but doesn't serve any static files.

Here is an excerpt from my settings.py:

```
STATIC_ROOT = ''

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = DOMAIN_URL + '/static/admin/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static'),
)
```

And from nginx.conf

```
server {
                listen 80;
                server_name localhost;
                # site_media - folder in uri for static files
                location /static/  {
                        autoindex on;
                        alias /project/app/static;
                        }
location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|p$
  access_log   off; # po co mi logi obrazków :)
  expires      30d;
}
                location / {
                        # host and port to fastcgi server
                        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8080;
                        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
                        fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
                        fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
                        fastcgi_param CONTENT_TYPE $content_type;
                        fastcgi_param CONTENT_LENGTH $content_length;
                        fastcgi_pass_header Authorization;
                        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
                        }
```

What do I do here?

Further, this is my nginx log

```
    WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_PORT required by WSGI!
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_PROTOCOL required by WSGI!" while read$
2012/04/17 13:48:24 [error] 15598#0: *3 open() "/etc/nginx/html/static/css/rese$
2012/04/17 13:48:24 [error] 15598#0: *4 open() "/etc/nginx/html/static/images/l$
2012/04/17 13:48:24 [error] 15598#0: *5 open() "/etc/nginx/html/static/js/scrip$
2012/04/17 13:48:24 [error] 15598#0: *6 open() "/etc/nginx/html/static/js/jquer$
2012/04/17 13:48:24 [error] 15598#0: *7 open() "/etc/nginx/html/static/style.cs$
2012/04/17 13:48:24 [error] 15598#0: *8 open() "/etc/nginx/html/static/js/jquer$
2012/04/17 13:48:24 [error] 15598#0: *5 open() "/etc/nginx/html/static/images/i$
2012/04/17 13:48:24 [error] 15598#0: *7 open() "/etc/nginx/html/static/images/i$
2012/04/17 13:48:24 [error] 15598#0: *8 open() "/etc/nginx/html/static/images/i$
2012/04/17 13:48:24 [error] 15598#0: *6 open() "/etc/nginx/html/static/images/s$
2012/04/17 13:48:24 [error] 15598#0: *3 open() "/etc/nginx/html/static/images/s$
2012/04/17 13:48:24 [error] 15598#0: *4 open() "/etc/nginx/html/static/images/s$
2012/04/17 14:07:33 [error] 16231#0: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "WSGIServer: mi$
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_PORT required by WSGI!
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_PROTOCOL required by WSGI!" while read$
2012/04/17 14:07:33 [error] 16231#0: *3 open() "/etc/nginx/html/static/css/rese$
2012/04/17 14:07:33 [error] 16231#0: *4 open() "/etc/nginx/html/static/style.cs$
2012/04/17 14:07:33 [error] 16231#0: *5 open() "/etc/nginx/html/static/js/jquer$
2012/04/17 14:07:33 [error] 16231#0: *6 open() "/etc/nginx/html/static/js/scrip$
2012/04/17 14:07:33 [error] 16231#0: *7 open() "/etc/nginx/html/static/js/jquer$
2012/04/17 14:07:34 [error] 16231#0: *7 open() "/etc/nginx/html/static/images/l$
2012/04/17 14:07:34 [error] 16231#0: *6 open() "/etc/nginx/html/static/images/i$
2012/04/17 14:07:34 [error] 16231#0: *4 open() "/etc/nginx/html/static/images/i$
2012/04/17 14:07:34 [error] 16231#0: *5 open() "/etc/nginx/html/static/images/i$
2012/04/17 14:07:34 [error] 16231#0: *3 open() "/etc/nginx/html/static/images/s$
2012/04/17 14:07:34 [error] 16231#0: *8 open() "/etc/nginx/html/static/images/s$
2012/04/17 14:07:34 [error] 16231#0: *5 open() "/etc/nginx/html/static/images/s$
2012/04/17 14:07:35 [error] 16231#0: *5 open() "/etc/nginx/html/static/images/f$
2012/04/17 14:10:30 [error] 16231#0: *9 FastCGI sent in stderr: "WSGIServer: mi$
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_PORT required by WSGI!
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_PROTOCOL required by WSGI!" while read$
2012/04/17 14:11:57 [error] 16471#0: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "WSGIServer: mi$
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_PORT required by WSGI!
WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_PROTOCOL required by WSGI!" while read$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question seems to be a  duplicate to [this one](https://serverfault.com/q/370525/52873). I've posted [very detailed answer](https://serverfault.com/a/370573/52873) there, it should help you. Please use search next time before you actually ask.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `alias /project/app/static;` needs a trailing slash so it should be: `alias /project/app/static/;`

Comment: tried that. didn't work.

Comment: trailing slash is not needed.