# Serving Django staticfiles via Nginx 404

Tags: nginx, django, uwsgi

I host my Djangoproject on Nginx with uwsgi. staticfiles need to be served separately by Nginx

```
server { 
    listen 80; 
    server_name blog.foo.de; 

    location /static { 
        root /home/user/blog/staticfiles; 
        access_log   off; 
        expires      30d; 
    } 

    location / {
       include uwsgi_params;
       uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/blog.socket;
    }

    access_log      /var/log/nginx/blog.access.log combined;
    error_log       /var/log/nginx/blog.error.log warn;
}
```

My STATIC_URL is set to http://blog.foo.de/static/
The folder /home/user/blog/staticfiles contains a folder static, where the files are collected into. so according to other posts here everything sholud work -- **but it doesn't.** the uwsgi part works just fine, but I only get a **404** when I try to access the static files.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't forget to add another `/static` to the `root`? You claim to have another level, but it doesn't reflect in the config.

Answer (score 0):

This needs some general cleanup:

- Your `server` block has two `location /` blocks, which is not permitted; one of them will be ignored. Use only one `location` block for any given location.
- Your `server` block has no `root` defined. Make sure that `root` is defined only in the `server` block, and not in the `location` blocks (unless a location needs a different root).

I also recommend not turning `off` the `access_log` or using `expires` while debugging, as this can make it more difficult to isolate the cause of a problem.

---

Though to really fix this, consider rewriting it entirely. A very short example:

```
server {
    location @django {
        include uwsgi_params; 
        uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/blog.socket; 
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @django;
    }
}
```

Comment: thx for your reply, but if there's only one location block allowed, how are [configs like this supposed to work](http://serverfault.com/questions/370525/nginxdjango-serving-static-files?rq=1) ?

Comment: None of the `location` blocks in that question or answer are duplicates, as yours is.

Comment: Ooops, the duplicate was just a mistake when I posted from my phone

Comment: It still doesn't work, but this config should look a bit cleaner:

    server {  
        listen 80;  
        server_name blog.orlives.de;  
      
        location @django {  
        include uwsgi_params;   
        uwsgi_pass unix:/tmp/blog.socket;   
    } 
  
    location / {  
        try_files $uri $uri/ @django;  
    }  
  
    location /static {  
        root /home/django/blog/staticfiles;  
        #access_log   off;  
        expires      0d;  
    }  
    access_log      /var/log/nginx/blog.access.log combined;  
    error_log       /var/log/nginx/blog.error.log warn;  
    }

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in for your staticfiles location

```
location ^~ /static/ {
    alias  /home/user/blog/staticfiles;
}
```

This link might help you for more details- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23226357/django-nginx-static-files-404